# Why the image converted by ndarray of the CNN output is not correct

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm try to test my CNN by showing the output to an image.

The source code is from https://xueyangfu.github.io/projects/tip2017.html

I run the origin code is useful.

And then I change some structure of CNN. I add some layers and change some parameters.

The training is right and I use some image to test the model.

I try to print the output ndarray and it contains correct values.

However, the image show by cv2 or plt are all same dark color in every pixels.
The shape and type of output ndarray and input ndarray are all the same of (height, width, 3), but the values of output ndarray can't write into the image.

I read the pure color image that save by the output ndarray. The shape of it becomes (height, width, 4). It add the value of 1. in each array, and the value of front three are different from my output ndarray.

I waste about a week in this strange problem. Please give me some advice about how to solve it or what the problem is.

Thank you for helping.

Below is the testing code:

```
import os
import training_0116 as DerainNet
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as np
import cv2

##################### Select GPU device ####################################
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"

file = "h.jpg"
ori = img.imread(file)
ori = ori/255.0
detail = ori
details = np.zeros([ori.shape[0], ori.shape[1], ori.shape[2]])
for j in range(3):
  tmp = detail[:,:,j]
  details[:,:,j] = np.pad(tmp, 0, 'symmetric')
details = np.expand_dims(details[:,:,:], axis = 0)


image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, details.shape[1], details.shape[2], details.shape[3]))

out = DerainNet.inference(image)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:

    if tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('./model/'):  
        ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model/')
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
        print ("load new model")

    else:
        saver.restore(sess, "./model/test-model/model") # this model uses 128 feature maps and for debug only                                                                   
        print ("load pre-trained model")                            


    detail_out  = sess.run(out, feed_dict={image:details})
    derained = detail_out[0,:, :, :]
    derained[np.where(derained < 0. )] = 0.
    derained[np.where(derained > 1. )] = 1.

    img.imsave("h_11.jpg",derained)
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)     
    plt.imshow(ori)      
    plt.title('input')   

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)    
    plt.imshow(derained)
    plt.title('output')   

    plt.show()
```

Below is the part of training code:

```
def inference(images):

  # conv1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_1'):
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16, 16, FLAGS.num_channels, FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-3), trainable=True, name='weights1')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases1')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

    conv1 = tf.nn.tanh(bias)
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

   # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_2'):
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, FLAGS.num_feature, FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-3), trainable=True, name='weights2')   
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases2')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

    conv2 = tf.nn.tanh(bias)
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_3'):
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 4, FLAGS.num_feature, FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-3), trainable=True, name='weights2')   
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases2')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

    conv3 = tf.nn.tanh(bias)
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_4'):
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([6, 6, FLAGS.num_feature, FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-3), trainable=True, name='weights2')   
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases2')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool3, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

    conv4 = tf.nn.tanh(bias)
    pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_6'):
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8, 8, FLAGS.num_channels,FLAGS.num_feature], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-3), trainable=True, name='weights3')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[FLAGS.num_channels], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='biases3')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv4,kernel,[tf.shape(images)[0], tf.shape(images)[1], tf.shape(images)[2], FLAGS.num_channels],[1, 1, 1, 1],padding='SAME')   
    conv5 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5, ksize=[1,3,3,1], strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

  return out
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ori = ori/255.0
```

Normalises the image as you read it in. Normal pixels will have values 0 to 255. For training, these are typically normalised to lie between 0 and 1. But if you want to view the image, you'll have to scale up the pixel values again. It's black because pixel values close to zero are very dark.

I think you want a corresponding

```
ori = ori*255
```

just before your imshow.

Comment: Not that problem. Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.

Comment: Yes, for training, you should use RGB in the range 0...1 but when you display them, they need to be in the range 0...255. I would expect "plt.imshow(ori)" to show you a very black image because all the pixels values are in the range 0...1.

Comment: 'ori' is the origin image and it shows correct. The dark image is the 'derained' one. Type and shape of 'ori' and 'derained' are all the same. However, only the pixels of the image from 'derained' are all the same without variety.